# Using async without await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2012, async-await, c#-5.0

I'd like to make a function async, so I simply add `async` like this:

```
public async static void something(){
}
```

You can see that its return-type is `void`. I just want this function to be called asynchronously  without blocking, since return is `void` so no `await` is needed.

But Visual Studio 2012 just cannot compile this, it says that I miss `await`?

Could you please advise a sample that makes a function `async` without using `await`.

Comment: Even more interesting is [async Methods correct? Resharper warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138523/async-methods-correct-resharper-warning)  when Resharper issues warning on `async` method having `await` in its body

Comment: @ГеннадийВанинНовосибирск, in that question Resharper is complaining about the two methods that don't have await in them, not the main method which does have await.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think that maybe you misunderstand what `async` does. The warning is exactly right: if you mark your method `async` but don't use `await` anywhere, then your method **won't be asynchronous**. If you call it, all the code inside the method will execute synchronously.

Also, you should try to avoid using `async void` methods, they make handling exceptions difficult.

Comment: `async` make the method itself asynchronous or not when the method get called, if no `await` anywhere inside the method? As above sample, if I call `something()`, will it block current thread?

Comment: Yes, if you have some long-running code inside `something()` (and no `await`), then it will block the thread. That's what the warning is trying to tell you.

Comment: ok, I think I understand wrong. If I do not want `something()` block current thread, I should put `async` in current method and use `something()`(which will not block) right?

Comment: `async` is not something that will make your methods magically not block. If you want to run some code on another thread, use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Ohh, got it, I misunderstand the concert, async mark the method is going to use async call not mean itself is async.

Comment: I'm still confused. I want to set an async function running without regard for return values or anything and just continue execution as if nothing happened. You're saying that omitting `await` will turn it into just a regular function call? I don't want to wait for it, I just want it to run and do its thing and die when it's finished.

Comment: @Patrick Then you can use `Task.Run()` to run it on another thread.

Comment: @svick Then why the same method will compile fine in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: @svick, right, await does not mean not blocking. However there is 0 value to async language feature unless at at some point it used to avoid blocking e.g. by not awaiting and async void method. You suggest Task,Run( ) and I agree, and this proves the point that the whole C# async feature is basically useless/incomplete in its current form. It's the software equivalent of the "Emperor's New Clothes".

Answer (score -1):

Change to

```
public async Task something(){
  return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      //TODO:
  }
}
```

You do not have to wait for the Task returned ;)

so alternatively You can just use a task and remove both async and await and then you get:

```
public Task something(){
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      //TODO:
  }
}
```

Task is implict void, if you do not use the generic return type argument