# async Methods correct? Resharper warning

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

in my Method `RecalcChartAsync` i do some time intensive stuff.. so i thought i'll do some things async.

I want to start the two Methods `CreateHistogramAsync` `CalculatePropValuesAsync` and in the meanwhile do some stuff in my `RecalcChartsAsync` and finally wait for it to complete.

```
 private async void RecalcChartsAsync()
{
    var histogram = CreateHistogramAsync();
    var propValues = CalculatePropValuesAsync();

    //do some other stuff

    await histogram;
    await propValues;
}

private async Task CreateHistogramAsync()
{
    //do some stuff
}

private async Task CalculatePropValuesAsync()
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Im not sure if i am doing it the right way because ReSharper gives me the following warning at the async Keyword at CreateHistogramAsync and CalculatePropValueAsync:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the await operator to await non-blocking API calls, ...

Now i am not sure if i am using this async thing in the correct way.

Comment: Always return Task<Foo>, when you implement async method. Otherwise you loose any connection to the method. This could be issue especially during testing.

Comment: Also if you want to wait for more tasks to finish, you can use `await Task.WhenAll(params Task[] tasks)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Now i am not sure if i am using this async thing in the correct way.

It doesn't sound like it. Just because you have an `async` method doesn't mean it's going to run on a separate thread - and it sounds like that's what you're expecting. When you execute an `async` method, it will run synchronously - i.e. just like normal - until it hits the first `await` expression. If you don't *have* any `await` expressions, that means it will just run as normal, the only difference being the way that it's wrapped up in a state machine, with the completion status (exceptions etc) represented by a task.

I suspect you should change your `CreateHistogramAsync` and `CalculatePropValuesAsync` methods to be just synchronous:

```
private void CreateHistogram()
{
    ...
}

private void CalculatePropValues()
{
    ...
}
```

and use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) to execute them in parallel:

```
private async void RecalcChartsAsync()
{
    var histogram = Task.Run((Action) CreateHistogram);
    var propValues = Task.Run((Action) CalculatePropValues);

    //do some other stuff

    await histogram;
    await propValues;
}
```

Comment: your code wont work this way.. i have to call `Task.Run(() => CreateHistogram());` or create an action/delegate. thx anyway your answer is still nice :)

Comment: @Hown_: Hmm... overloading and method group conversions are a nasty combination. A simple cast should work though - edited...

Comment: @Hown_: Did you try it? Note that I'm casting the *method group*, not an *invocation of the method*. I've just tried it in a sample project and it's fine.

Comment: ahhhh thank you. totally my failure.. your guess was right! i casted an invocation of the method ;) !! awsome!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing you're awaiting on within your methods, so marking then as `async` is pointless. That's why ReSharper is warning you.

You should start from learning how `async`/`await` works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are not awaiting anything in your two last methods, then remove the async from the declaration.  In this case, creating and returning the task will be enough to achieve what you want.