# Async with await do not work. Why?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

When I try to run the code below, perform synchronous operations. **Why?**

I get the following warning ...

*Warning  1   This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.*

```
private async void btProcessa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ProcessaA();
    await ProcessaB();
}

public async Task ProcessaA()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        pbProcessoA.Value = i;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

public async Task ProcessaB()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        pbProcessoB.Value = i;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the detailed message do you not understand? We need to know to answer specifically.

Comment: this question looks like a dupe to [Using async without await](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016567/using-async-without-await)

Answer (score 10):

`async` does not mean "run this code on a background thread". If you want to know more about `async`, I have an [introductory blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) are great, and there's a [full guide to the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

If you want to do some simulation of I/O-bound (or event-based) operations, you should use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`:

```
public async Task ProcessaA()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  {
    pbProcessoA.Value = i;
    await Task.Delay(500);
  }
}
```

If you want to simulate CPU-bound operations, then you should be pushing them off to a background task via `Task.Run`:

```
public async Task ProcessaA()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  {
    pbProcessoA.Value = i;
    await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); });
  }
}
```

Comment: MSDN [Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx) is also must-read.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this example to a real production system. Save the entities in a database can take time. Look at this elegant simulation

```
class TestAsyncAwait
{
    public void GetEntities()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var a = getEntities(i);
            saveEntitiesAsync(a);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to close\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private List<string> getEntities(int i)
    {
        Console.Write("getting Entities for id={0}...", i);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var r = new List<string> { i.ToString(), " Hello!" };
        Console.WriteLine("done, has the Entities for id={0}\n", i);
        return r;
    }

    async void saveEntitiesAsync(List<string> a)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(4000); // simulates long task
            foreach (string s in a) sb.Append(s);
        });
        // shows the thread in action
        Trace.WriteLine("saved: " + sb.ToString());
    }
}
```