# Using async without await?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

Consider [Using async without await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016567/using-async-without-await).

> think that maybe you misunderstand what async does. The warning is
> exactly right: if you mark your method async but don't use await
> anywhere, then your method won't be asynchronous. If you call it, all
> the code inside the method will execute synchronously.

I want to write a method that should run async but don't need use await. For example when use a thread

```
public async Task PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo)
{
    Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId,
}
```

I want call `PushCallAsync` and run async and don't want to use await.

Can I use async without await in C#?

Comment: @J.Steen so if use this run async?

Comment: Well. It's all up to what your design issue is, here. What do you expect "async" to do?

Comment: Without `await` your method will execute `Synchronously`

Comment: @J.Steen i want run in other thread

Comment: If you're not going to await this method why bother declaring it async at all? The text that you quote sums it up pretty nicely IMO.

Comment: Run in other thread. Sure. Do you want to wait for it to finish? Or just fire-and-forget? From the content, looks like just a fire-and-forget.

Comment: I think you just use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) directly. `async`/`await` isn't really a multithreading mechanism, in fact I think the runtime executes things on as few threads as possible. It's mostly about the compiler automatically transform your code into continuation-passing style so you only *wait for results* (or completion) of a background operation when absolutely necessary. When you don't need to wait (or `await`) for the results of your call, this is not the language feature you're looking for.

Comment: See also what the docs have to say about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_Threads (I was wrong, there's just a *single* thread and nonblocking IO involved.

Comment: @millimoose: The way `async` interacts with threads is a bit more complex, and the default behavior can be easily overridden. `async` is not a multithreading mechanism, nor does it always run on a single thread. [I have a blog post that summarizes how `async` schedules its continuations](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary So it'd be fairer to say that (as far as the OP needs to be concerned) an `async` method achieves asynchronicity using some mechanism appropriate to the use case, and that this mechanism can be considered an implementation detail? And that from this follows that merely declaring a method as `async` does not in fact introduce asynchronicity, and the keyword serves only to trigger the compiler rewrites from sequential style to CPS.

Comment: @millimoose: Not an implementation detail. It is clearly specified - and has to be, so its behavior is always predictable and reliable (once you understand the mechanism).

Answer (score 42):

You still are misunderstanding `async`. The `async` keyword does *not* mean "run on another thread".

To push some code onto another thread, you need to do it explicitly, e.g., `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(() => Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId));
```

I have an [`async`/`await` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

Comment: is Task.Run can be not awaited?

Comment: @toha: I don't understand your question. The `Task.Run` is `await`ed.

Comment: I use task, and not await. but sometimes it is not called until completed.. when out of the function block.. I hope the task running until complete even main process out of function block. can it be done? If I use await it is takes long time so I need It is not awaited and called until finished even out of function call

Comment: @toha: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you ask your own question?

Comment: No the question is same.. I am not await my async task. but I use it on Exception Block and the async Task function is not completely finish when awaiting another function call I think this is about async task life cycle when fired not await and on exception block.. do you have article about that Sir?

Comment: @toha: Please see [this series](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).

Comment: excellent! I will read that thank You. Types of async , Durable, non durable, etc I will learn this

Answer (score 37):

If your `Logger.LogInfo` is already async this is enough:

```
public void PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo)
{
    Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId,
}
```

If it is not just start it async without waiting for it

```
public void PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo)
{
    Task.Run(() => Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId));
}
```

Comment: I read it, seems to me more like a style difference than an actual difference in bahavior, isn't it?

Comment: No. `Task.Run` uses different defaults: `DenyChildAttach` and `TaskScheduler.Default`. The `TaskScheduler` is particularly important because `StartNew` will use `TaskScheduler.Current` by default, which makes it schedule the delegate differently based on the context of the caller. This has tripped up so many people that many teams have adopted code rules that never allow `StartNew` unless the `TaskScheduler` is specified.

Comment: Didn't know that, thx for the info. Changed the code to Task.Run

Comment: By convention you should not name a method "Async" unless it has the "async" keyword.

Comment: If your Logger.LogInfo is already async this is enough: >> My method is already async but when I debug it, the code exit before completion to finish.. how to make sure LogInfo is always exit until finish and with no await ?

Answer (score 6):

You're misunderstanding `async`.
It actually just tells the Compiler to propagate the inversion of control flow it does in the background for you. So that the whole method stack is marked as async.

What you actually want to do depends on your problem. (Let's consider your call `Logger.LogInfo(..)` is an `async` method as it does eventually call File.WriteAsync() or so.

- If you calling function is a void event handler, you're good. The async call will happen to some degree (namely File.WriteAsync) in the background. You do not expect any result in your control flow. That is fire and forget.
- If however you want to do anything with the result or if you want to continue only then, when `Logger.LogInfo(..)` is done, you have to do precautions. This is the case when your method is somehow *in the middle of* the call-stack. Then `Logger.LogInfo(..)` will usually return a `Task` and that you can wait on. But beware of calling task.Wait() because it will dead lock your GUI-Thread. Instead use await or return the Task (then you can omit async):

```
public void PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo) 
{
   return Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId); 
}
```

or

```
 public async void PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo) 
 {
    await Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId); 
 }
```

Comment: You should not use `async void` unless it is an event handler.  That is the only acceptable time and is the only correct way of making an async event handler.  If your synchronous method is `void`, it should be `async Task`.  This is due to exception handling where event handlers will throw on the `SynchronizationContext` (similarly to synchronous events) rather than the caller.  If possible the async event handler should be a thin private wrapper an `async Task` function (so it can be tested or re-used).

Comment: @GraemeWicksted you are certainly right and I support 'do not do async void' but for the understanding it is what I need - and eventually you'll usually have async void somewhere

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reply. How is it justified here? Looks like it should be `async Task` to me as it is not an event handler.  Remember: `async Task` is essentially `async Task<void>` but the latter simply does not exist.  The only difference between `async void` and `async Task` is exception propagation and it only makes sense on event handlers. I have not observed a concrete example that would indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If Logger.LogInfo is a synchronous method, the whole call will be synchronous anyway. If all you want to do is to execute the code in a separate thread, async is not the tool for the job. Try with thread pool instead:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( foo => PushCallAsync(callNotificationInfo) );
```

Comment: Favour the Parallel Task library, rather than calling the threadpool directly... this can have rather unforeseen consequences depending on the platform (WinRT, Win, WP8, etc). In my experience. =)

Comment: You got me interested... Could you please provide more details on what the consequences could be?

Comment: Well. I've managed to completely choke the CPU on several devices, using `QueueUserWorkItem` (using only two threads, mind you, so it's touchy as well), whereas the Task library will manage it perfectly. I've also had an issue where I've queued several threads, and none reaches the callback until they're all done, in a sort of thread-avalanche.

Comment: Consider [this question and its answers, and further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200573/threadpool-queueuserworkitem-vs-task-factory-startnew).

Comment: *If Logger.LogInfo is not a synchronous method* don't you mnean If *Logger.LogInfo **is** a synchronous method*??

Answer (score 2):

Given your example

```cs
public async Task PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo)
{
    Logger.LogInfo("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId,
}
```

- Logger.LogInfo is called synchronously
- The `async` keyword gives the method `PushCallAsync` the **capability to `await`**, but it never awaits anything

If your intention is to make the method run asynchronously - as the name `PushCallAsync` fittingly implies too -, you have find an alternative to synchronously calling LogInfo.

If a `LogInfoAsync` method exists, trying to evade using `await` is ill-advised. Await is important because:

- It captures and throws exceptions that may occur on the task execution - which would otherwise be lost / unhandled
- It ensures execution order by waiting for the result

If you specifically want a *fire-and-forget behavior*, where you do not depend on execution order (e.g. in this case don't care about order of the log messages), you call `LogInfoAsync()` without awaiting the result.

Since you don't use any `await` you do not mark the method `async`. What makes it asynchronous is not the `async` keyword but it calling other methods asynchronously.

```cs
public Task PushCallAsync(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo)
{
    // Fire and forget - we do not care about the result, failure, or order of this log message
    _ = Logger.LogInfoAsync("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId,
    Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

or non-async

```cs
public void PushCall(CallNotificationInfo callNotificationInfo)
{
    // Fire and forget - we do not care about the result, failure, or order of this log message
    _ = Logger.LogInfoAsync("Pushing new call {0} with {1} id".Fill(callNotificationInfo.CallerId,
}
```

Not that the method name *Push* implies it is in order. So I would name it differently if you really don't care about order. Otherwise, as Push implies, using await would be correct to ensure order.