# Javascript: await function endend before loop continue

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

i've a similar situation

```
array.forEach(item => {
 function_fetch(item)
})
```

now i need that before that loop continue he await that the function end and do what have to do, then recall the function with the other item

Comment: Without seeing the inner function it's impossible to help you.  Please modify the question to include a **[mcve]** - use the snippet button in the editor -> `<>`

Comment: Maybe [your async function doesn't contain an `await` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45594596/6320039)?

Comment: even if you have await in your foreach it must be forEach(async (item) => {}) which will return a promise and you will have to wait for the same as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can not use await in forEach function directly.

So you can use simple for of loop.

```
async function fetching () {
  for ( const item of array) {
    await function_fetch(item)
  }
}
```

await function should be inside any async function only.