# What will be the output of this node/es6 code and why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was presented this coding question on a job application and I want to learn and understand, so here is the code question and then I will provide my interpretation and ask the SO community to elaborate/correct my interpretation:

```
async function someFunction() {
    console.log('someFunction'):
}

console.log('start');
someFunction();
console.log('end');
```

The output here is arguably unpredictable in my opinion, the order now, simply because we know the implementation of `someFunction` starts with a `console.log` will be:

- start
- someFunction
- end

**I have run this code in my browser and I do see that it always runs in this order. I am just not sure as to the reason why.**

**Reading online, "forgetting" the `await` keyword for the execution of `async someFunction` the function will still execute asynchronously.**

My reasoning is that, albeit `someFunction` is async and returns a promise, the first line of execution of someFunction will occur before console.log('end'). I am not sure why many developers think that these are good hiring questions, perhaps they are. I just find them to be trick questions that are not real world. In the real world, the promise returned by `someFunction` would be handled, for example:

```
console.log('start');
await someFunction();
console.log('end');
```

I would appreciate an explanation of this code please.

Comment: It's completely deterministic - `async function`s will halt at the first `await`. Since there isn't any it's basically the same as a normal function.

Comment: you can run this in your browser's console and see the exact answer

Comment: Also, why this is a good question: *it's important". Imagine you have `async () {nonAsuncMutation(); await someFn(); differentNonAsyncMutation()}` if you want both non-async functions to run *together* you put them before or after the `await`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes but see my question change, in the real world, you put await from someFunction(); you do not call an async function like a normal function, that is just bad coding yes?

Comment: Yep, there is no `await`, hence the function is executed synchronously.

Comment: @VLAZ Ok I do not understand, reading online, if you forget the await keyword the function will still execute async

Comment: But the async function *won't*. This is the important part an async function is only *partly* executed asynchronously - only the code after `await`. Any code *before* `await` is synchronous and will always be run in the same sequence as the other code before and after the function invocation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async function without await in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594596/async-function-without-await-in-javascript)

Comment: There are many real-world `async` functions that aren't awaited. In fact, you can't `await` in top level scope (but you can `then` it).

Comment: @BrianOgden [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612969/different-behavior-of-async-functions-when-assigning-temporary-to-variable/) is an actual example of the placement of `await` making a difference. If you do `result = await getResult(); array = array.concat(result)` that's *different* to `array = array.concat(await getResult())` even if normally inlining a variable will not make a difference. More generally, you can have the same problem with `myVar = myVar + await getResult()` - anything that mutates a variable and different timings of when it happens lead to different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order here is completely deterministic it will always be `start` -> `someFunction` -> `end`:

```js
async function someFunction() {
    console.log('someFunction');
}

console.log('start');
someFunction();
console.log('end');
```

This is because only an `await` will pause the execution of an async function. Any code before an `await` will be executed synchronously, while any code after an `await` will only run after the promise `await`ed is resolved:

```js
async function someFunction() {
  console.log('someFunction - before await');
  
  await otherFunction();
  
  console.log('someFunction - after await');
}

async function otherFunction() {
  console.log('otherFunction');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('promise resolved');
      resolve();
    }, 0);
});
}

console.log('start');
someFunction();
console.log('end');
```

This can come into play if you have non-trivial async functions that might do multiple actions and it *matters* what order they are in:

```js
//sample shared variable
let counter = 1;

async function someFunction() {
  console.log('someFunction - before await counter is:', counter);
  
  let awaitResult = await otherFunction();
  
  console.log('someFunction - after await counter is: ', counter, '\nawaited function returned: ', awaitResult);
}

async function otherFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(counter);
    }, 0);
});
}

someFunction();
counter += 1;
```

This is a dumbed down example but it showcases what can happen - if you read `someFunction` you could assume that `counter` has the same value both times. But that's not correct, since the mutation of the variable happens after the first read and before the second one. The `await` is what makes the difference.