# Different behavior of async functions when assigning temporary to variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, promise, async-await

Why a different result in the following cases? The first example works correctly, returns an array of three elements `["qwe", "rty", "asd"]`. Second example return only last element `["asd"]`. Please, explain how it work? Why is this behavior happening?

In the first example working through intermediate variable `awaitResult`.

```js
class XXX {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = {1: ['qwe'], 2: ['rty'], 3: ['asd']}
  }

  async getValue(key) {
    return this.storage[key];
  }

  async logValues() {
    let keys = [1, 2, 3]
    let values = []

    // ----- First version -----

    await Promise.all(
      keys.map(
        async key => {
          let awaitResult = await this.getValue(key)
          values = values.concat(awaitResult)
        }
      )
    );

    console.log(values)
  }
}

let xxx = new XXX()
xxx.logValues()
```

In the second example working without `awaitResult`.

```js
class XXX {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = {1: ['qwe'], 2: ['rty'], 3: ['asd']}
  }

  async getValue(key) {
    return this.storage[key];
  }

  async logValues() {
    let keys = [1, 2, 3]
    let values = []

    // ----- Second version -----
   
    await Promise.all(
      keys.map(
        async key => values = values.concat(await this.getValue(key)),
      )
    );

    console.log(values)
  }
}

let xxx = new XXX()
xxx.logValues()
```

Comment: This is an odd way to build your `values` array. Why not use `values = await Promise.all(...)`, with the promise resolution function returning the actual data you need?

Comment: Your first version doesn't return any values from the map callback. I'm surprised it works.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk it works through *two* side-effects that are not design decisions. 1. `.map` shouldn't be used to do iteration and mutation. It's basically a `forEach` (or `for`) that is there. The mapping is irrelevant. 2. `await Promise.all` *works* but for a completely different reason. `await` will cause the async function to pause until the promise is resolved. `await Promise.all` returns a promise but since there is (essentially) no arguments it's given it just resolves automatically. This still is still queued on the event loop after all the `await`s in the `map` callbacks are resolved.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk [here is a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/daqekoh/edit?js,console) of this re-written *slightly* more clearly showing what happens. The `await Promise.all` is a bit misleading, so I've moved that as a separate statement `await new Promise((r) => {r()});` (await an auto-resolved promise) to show what role it has in the process.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah, the fact that the Promise.all gets queued because of the awaits inside the map callback was not clear to me. That's... interesting, but certainly not clean code O_O

Comment: @IceMetalPunk it's absolutely bad practive, you're not wrong. `.map` shouldn't be used as it's used here for iteration and `await Promise.all` shouldn't be used if you're not awaiting promises. Using an external shared `values` is also a bad idea. All in all, this should be done through the promises API - *do* use `Promise.all` but give it multiple promises and use `.then()` to combine the results that come back and *then* return them.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from [Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613169/) is absolutely correct. I just want to expand upon it with some clarification, as there are two key things one needs to understand:

## Async functions are *actually* partially synchronous

This, I think, is the most important thing. Here is the thing - knowledge of async functions 101:

1. They will execute *later*.
2. They return a Promise.

But point one is actually wrong. Async functions will run *synchronously* until they encounter an `await` keyword followed by a Promise, and *then* pause, wait until the Promise is resolved and continue:

```js
function getValue() {
  return 42;
}

async function notReallyAsync() {
  console.log("-- function start --");
  
  const result = getValue();
  
  console.log("-- function end --");
  
  return result;
}


console.log("- script start -");

notReallyAsync()
  .then(res => console.log(res));

console.log("- script end -");
```

So, `notReallyAsync` will run to completion when called, since there is no `await` in it. It still returns a Promise which will only be put on the event queue and resolved on a next iteration of the event loop.

However, if it *does* have `await`, then the function *pauses* at that point and any code *after* the `await` will only be run after the Promise is resolved:

```js
function getAsyncValue() {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
}

async function moreAsync() {
  console.log("-- function start --");
  
  const result = await getAsyncValue();
  
  console.log("-- function end --");
  
  return result;
}

console.log("- script start -");

moreAsync()
  .then(res => console.log(res));

console.log("- script end -");
```

So, this is absolutely the key to understanding what's happening. The second part is really just a consequence of this first part

## Promises are always resolved *after* the current code has run

Yes, I mentioned it before but still - promise resolution happens as part of the event loop execution. There are probably better resources online but I wrote a simple (I hope) outline of how it works [as part of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459913/). If you get the basic idea of the event loop there - good, that's all you need, the basics.

Essentially, any code that runs *now* is within the current execution of the event loop. Any promise will be resolved the *next* iteration the earliest. If there are multiple Promises, then you might need to wait few iterations. Whatever the case, it happens *later*.

## So, how this all applies here

To make it more clear, here is the explanation:
Code *before* `await` will be completed synchronously with the *current* values of anything it references while code *after* `await` will happen the next event loop:

```js
let awaitResult = await this.getValue(key)
values = values.concat(awaitResult)
```

means that the value will be awaited *first*, then upon resolution `values` will be fetched and `awaitResult` will be concatenated to it. If we represent what happens in sequence, you would get something like:

```js
let values = [];

//function 1: 
let key1 = 1;
let awaitResult1;
awaitResult1 = await this.getValue(key1); //pause function 1 wait until it's resolved

//function 2:
key2 = 2;
let awaitResult2;
awaitResult2 = await this.getValue(key2); //pause function 2 and wait until it's resolved

//function 3:
key3 = 3;
let awaitResult3;
awaitResult3 = await this.getValue(key3); //pause function 3 and wait until it's resolved

//...event loop completes...
//...next event loop starts 
//the Promise in function 1 is resolved, so the function is unpaused
awaitResult1 = ['qwe'];
values = values.concat(awaitResult1);

//...event loop completes...
//...next event loop starts 
//the Promise in function 2 is resolved, so the function is unpaused
awaitResult2 = ['rty'];
values = values.concat(awaitResult2);

//...event loop completes...
//...next event loop starts 
//the Promise in function 3 is resolved, so the function is unpaused
awaitResult3 = ['asd'];
values = values.concat(awaitResult3);
```

So, you would get all of the values added correctly together in one array.

However, the following:

```js
values = values.concat(await this.getValue(key))
```

means that *first* `values` will be fetched and *then* the function pauses to await the resolution of `this.getValue(key)`. Since `values` will always be fetched *before* any modifications have been made to it, then the value is always an empty array (the starting value), so this is equivalent to the following code:

```js
let values = [];

//function 1:
values = [].concat(await this.getValue(1)); //pause function 1 and wait until it's resolved
//       ^^ what `values` is always equal during this loop

//function 2:
values = [].concat(await this.getValue(2)); //pause function 2 and wait until it's resolved
//       ^^ what `values` is always equal to at this point in time

//function 3:
values = [].concat(await this.getValue(3)); //pause function 3 and wait until it's resolved
//       ^^ what `values` is always equal to at this point in time

//...event loop completes...
//...next event loop starts 
//the Promise in function 1 is resolved, so the function is unpaused
values = [].concat(['qwe']);

//...event loop completes...
//...next event loop starts 
//the Promise in function 2 is resolved, so the function is unpaused
values = [].concat(['rty']);

//...event loop completes...
//...next event loop starts 
//the Promise in function 3 is resolved, so the function is unpaused
values = [].concat(['asd']);
```

Bottom line - the position of `await` *does* affect how the code runs and can thus its semantics.

## Better way to write it

This was a pretty lengthy explanation but the actual root of the problem is that this code is not written correctly:

1. Running `.map` for a simple looping operation is bad practice. It should be used to do a *mapping* operation - a 1:1 transformation of each element of the array to another array. Here, `.map` is merely a loop.
2. `await Promise.all` should be used when there *are* multiple Promises to await.
3. `values` is a shared variable between async operations which can run into common problems with all asynchronous code that accesses a common resource - "dirty" reads or writes can change the resource from a *different* state than it actually is in. This is what happens in the second version of the code where each write uses the *initial* `values` instead of what it currently holds.

Using these appropriately we get:

1. Use `.map` to make an array of Promises.
2. Use `await Promise.all` to wait until all of the above are resolved.
3. Combine the results into `values` *synchronously* when the Promises have been resolved.

```js
class XXX {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = {1: ['qwe'], 2: ['rty'], 3: ['asd']}
  }

  async getValue(key) {
  console.log()
    return this.storage[key];
  }

  async logValues() {
  console.log("start")
    let keys = [1, 2, 3]

    let results = await Promise.all( //2. await all promises
      keys.map(key => this.getValue(key)) //1. convert to promises
    );
    
    let values = results.reduce((acc, result) => acc.concat(result), []); //3. reduce and concat the results
    console.log(values);
  }
}

let xxx = new XXX()
xxx.logValues()
```

This can also be folded into the Promise API as running `Promise.all().then`:

```js
class XXX {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = {1: ['qwe'], 2: ['rty'], 3: ['asd']}
  }

  async getValue(key) {
  console.log()
    return this.storage[key];
  }

  async logValues() {
  console.log("start")
    let keys = [1, 2, 3]

    let values = await Promise.all( //2. await all promises
      keys.map(key => this.getValue(key)) //1. convert to promises
    )
    .then(results => results.reduce((acc, result) => acc.concat(result), []));//3. reduce and concat the results
     
    console.log(values);
  }
}

let xxx = new XXX()
xxx.logValues()
```

Answer (score 2):

Concurrency. Or more precisely: A non atomic modification of `values`.

First of all, the `values.concat(...)` get evaluated, at that time `values` is an empty array. Then all the functions `await`. Then, all the `values =` get run, concatenating the awaited element to *the empty array*, and assigning those arrays with one value to `values`. The last resolved value wins.

To fix:

```
 await Promise.all(
  keys.map(
    async key => {
       const el = await this.getValue(key); // async operation
      values = values.concat(el); // atomic update
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: OK, this makes sense now. I was wondering what's happening but you're right. Just to clarify if somebody else still doesn't get it - `const el = await something()` followed by `value.concat(el)` will resolve `values` ***after*** the async operation finishes. while `values.concat(await something())` will ***first*** resolve `values` as `[]` and *then* pause for the async operation to finish. So the equivalent code in the second case is `[].concat(await something())` as `values` will always be an empty array before firing the async operations.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm quite busy right now, feel free to clarify the answer :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the quick and short answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change how you're computing `values`, because you can make `Promise.all` entirely responsible for this:

```js
  async logValues() {
    const mapFn = async(key) => this.getValue(key);
    const values = await Promise.all(this.keys.map(mapFn));
    console.log(values)
    return values;
  }
```

Note that this works because we're using a one-line arrow function: it automatically returns the result of the function statement (which is **not** the case when you split your arrow function body over multiple lines with curly brackets).

Also I assume `keys` isn't actually the array [1,2,3], because that would be weird, but if you *do* need a sequence of numbers, and you don't want to hardcode that array, `new Array(n).fill().map( (_,index) => console.log(index) )` where `n` is some number should do the trick.