# nodejs `a.unshift(x)` vs `a = [x].concat(a)`, do they behave differently in the asynchronous scenario?

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous

Will the following codes behaves different in asynchronous scenario?

```
a.unshift(x)

a = [x].concat(a)
```

How do I verify that?

Since unshift operates on the array directly, while the assignment `=` will create a new array.

So I am wondering if they are running among massive code and there are asynchronous function that invoking them, will they behaves differently?

Will it happen to lose something when using `.concat`?

Example:

```
let a = []
a = ['a'].concat(a)
a = ['b'].concat(a)
a = ['c'].concat(a)

// a = ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Normally the above code are equivalent to the followings:

```
let a = []
a = a.unshift('a')
a = a.unshift('b')
a = a.unshift('c')

// a = ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

But will the later one be more secure? What if in some rare cases, while the `a = [x].concat(a)` is still in progress, the other places changed the `a`, and after the `a = [x].concat(a)` completes, the previous change would be lost.

Will this happen?

Comment: None of those functions are asynchronous. What do you mean by "asynchronous scenario"?

Comment: They are invoked by some asynchronous functions.

Comment: You will get a different behaviour than expected if you have something like `arr.concat(await somePromise)` and that line is executed multiple times. If you use `arr.unshift(await somePromise)` then you would be fine. However, this can easily be amended by having `await` and the addition on different lines `let value = await somePromise; arr = arr.concat(value)` will perform as expected.

Comment: You can see an example [of `arr.concat(await somePromise)` playing badly with asynchronicity here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612969/different-behavior-of-async-functions-when-assigning-temporary-to-variable/)

Comment: Conceptually & actually, javascript is a single-threaded language. It won't suffer that abrupt thread shift you'll see in languages like C/C++. The ambiguity you're eluding to only occurs in the deferred processing of code blocks marked as asynchronous --  e.g., await & promises. So if you had `await unshift` for example, you may see the disorder.