# async function without await keyword inside

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I always thought async functions need to contain "await" keyword inside, for example:

```
async function doTask() {
 let total = await CustomFunction(values);
 console.log(`Main Total: ${total}`);
}
doTask();
```

But I also saw some like that define async function without having await as:

```
GetData = async ( method, url, params) =>
{
    Axios.request({
        method, url, params
    });
}
```

so what's the point to have async keyword added in front of a function that doesn't have "await" keyword?

Comment: Because you can now `await` *that* function. It's impossible to have every single async function containing `await`, as they have to `await` *something*. If every single one just `awaits` and is hence `async`, then where is the original function that they all use `await` for?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594596/async-function-without-await-in-javascript all the answers posted here are copied from here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async function without await in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594596/async-function-without-await-in-javascript)

Comment: It’s also not unlikely that the person who wrote this code didn’t know what `async` really does.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your example it probably is a bug; I guess there should be a `return await` in front of `Axios.request`.

But in general, unless the caller explicitly only accepts functions returning a Promise, there is no point in declaring an await-less function async.

Answer (score 0):

In simple word if you use `await` in front of any async function it will keep waiting for request to success.

For in your example :

```js
async function doTask() {
 let total = await CustomFunction(values);
 console.log(`Main Total: ${total}`);
 return total;
}
doTask();
```

In above example if you call `doTask()` then `total` will contains the result of request. But if you don't use await then total may not contains result of request.

```js
async function doTask() {
 let total = CustomFunction(values);
 console.log(`Main Total: ${total}`);
 return total;
}
doTask();
```

Now, If you call `doTask()` then it will may return `undefined` or `null` instead of actual request.

Answer (score 0):

Marking function as async but without await inside is a bad practice because it forces your transpiling tool (babel/typescript) to add some additional code to resulting bundle.
See [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwE4FMCOCuIyAFAJQwDeAsAFAyM67ILZYAK26AtqiLgB0eEOgA2AN1ykAjOQDc9AL716oSLEQoMWAOYsK1ek2at2MLr35CR4qaQBMC5UA) with typescript, try to remove/add async word.
But code without await will work synchronously as Juhil Somaiya said.