# Is it necessary to use await for analytics().logEvent?

Tags: react-native-firebase

Sometimes some of my events do not get logged in the Firebase DebugView and I'm currently trying to find out why.

We decided about leaving out the `await` for `firebase.analytics().logEvent(...)`, and now I wonder if that could lead to the missing events. In my understanding this should not make a difference in the behavior, because I don't have to wait for the event to be logged.

So my question is: Does it make a difference in reliability of the event logging in the following two cases?

```js
// With await
await firebase.analytics().logEvent('event_name');

// Without await
firebase.analytics().logEvent('event_name');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`firebase.analytics().*` gives u a promise which you need to handle. Under the hood the methods call the firebase app which optimizes communications to Firebase GA servers. You can enable logs

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
```

and watch them with

```
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

**Update 2023-05-23**:
More generic question "do we need to await async calls?" is answered here [Does an async function always need to be called with await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953976/does-an-async-function-always-need-to-be-called-with-await)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Specifically, is there a decrease in reliability if we don't await for the log event?

Comment: I guess the more generic question is "do we need to await async calls?". It is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953976/does-an-async-function-always-need-to-be-called-with-await.

Comment: Personally, I experienced a situation where using the logs gathered in this way it seemed that an event was actually reported to Firebase, but I didn't see it in the DebugView. It seems that sometimes events can appear there with a little delay