# Using `await` when caller does not expect a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have a very simple express app which stores information it receives from clients into a database without hardly any processing. Some simplified code to illustrate this:

```js
app.post(ANALYTICS_ENDPOINT, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await insertToDB(req.body)
    res.status(204).send();
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

This application is deployed to google cloud run and handles a high volume of requests per second. What we have noticed is that removing the `await` keyword from the route allows each container to handle more requests, at the downside of not capturing errors - so clients will always receive a `204`.

The other use of await in this would be in `insertToDB` function which again simplified looks like this:

```js
const insertToDB = async (row) => {
  await dbClient.insert(row);
}
```

As you can see here we are also using `await` since this action returns a Promise.

So the question is, should we be awaiting when the caller does not expect a response? And can it be the case that avoiding these awaits we can handle more throughput on our app?

EDIT:
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953976/does-an-async-function-always-need-to-be-called-with-await). Yet I think this is different as I am mostly interested in understanding why removing the `await` allows me to handle 2/3x the number of requests per second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an async function always need to be called with await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953976/does-an-async-function-always-need-to-be-called-with-await)

Comment: A throughput depends on a bottleneck. If it's db, it stays the same, but you have less control over it. It's your decision to respond with success regardless of the result or wait for a promise. If it's not waited, it's obviously harder to detect the problem because it looks ok on client side. In this case the obvious problem is that an error won't be handled. If async job is separated from a request, at least make sure errors are handled and logged

Comment: It does not appear the OP has written a clear question that describes what they're really attempting to ask.  If you attempt to answer this part of their question ***So the question is, should we be awaiting when the caller does not expect a response?***, you will get downvoted because they don't actually want an answer that discusses that at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 what is the point of what you are doing here? I do want answer, just not a paragraph on generic coding best practices which can be summarised as "you should handle errors". I do however thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

You should wait because your db call is `async`, so you must wait the insertion to be made before return to the client.

You can simply use promise resolution to be more concise and clear:

```
app.post(ANALYTICS_ENDPOINT, async (req, res) => {
    insertToDB(req.body)
    .then(() => res.status(204).send())
    .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
});
```

Comment: How is it more concise and clear? async..await is supposed to replace raw promises, and now they are brought back.

Comment: "You should wait": this would need a stronger argument.

Comment: Yeah as the other comments have mentioned, there is no explanation for the points made.