# should I use `await` when calling an `async` function inside another `async` function?

Tags: typescript

I have an `async` function which calls another `async` function:

```
const func1 = async () => {...}

const func2 = async () => {func1()}
```

I wonder does it still make sense or unnecessary at all to use `await` to call `func1()` inside `func2` ?

```
const func2 = async () => {await func1()}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to wait for `func1()` to finish? If not, then you don't need to `await` it.

Comment: You can either await for the result and do something with it. If you do not need the result in that function just return the result of the function call without async/await.  `const func2 = () => {return func1()}` which will return the Promise that is returned from `func1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953976/does-an-async-function-always-need-to-be-called-with-await

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the correct thing to do is `await` the nested function.

If you do not `await` the `func1`, it executes in a "fire and forget" mode, so you can't tell if it failed or not, and any lines of code below it in `func2` may execute before `func1` completes.

The only time it makes a lot of sense to not await is if you want to return a promise from your function.

Ex:

```
const func2 = async () => { return func1(); }

await func2();
```

When you `return` the promise, then that promise is awaited if you use await when calling `func2`

Comment: I thought whether you await or not, you will still get back a Promise, if it's a Promise that you are returning.

Comment: `await` will not change the return type. The difference is in how you handle the result of the `Promise`. If you `await` then the current function doesn't continue until the `Promise` resolves, and if the `Promise` errors the exception bubbles up into the current function. If you do not `await`, then the current function keeps running and any exception in the `Promise` is ignored.

Comment: I’m just confused over what you said — to not to await if you want to return a Promise. In your example, whether you await in nested func1 or not, doesn’t they both return Promise?