# In WebdriverIO, why does the `expect` line require an `await` in front of it to correctly test something?

Tags: es6-promise, webdriver-io

This is a somewhat advanced question about WebdriverIO and ES6 JavaScript promises:

I just followed the instructions on WebdriverIO to create the project:

```sh
npx wdio TryWDIO
cd TryWDIO
```

and then I modified the test file:

```js
// test/specs/example.e2e.js

describe('Trying it', () => {
  it('should have some text', async () => {
    await browser.url('https://www.amazon.com');
    const elem = await $('body');

    await expect(elem).toHaveTextContaining('Best Sellers');
  });
});
```

and run it using

```sh
npm run wdio
```

and so the test passed.

And if I change that last line to

```js
await expect(elem).toHaveTextContaining('BBBest Sellers');
```

The test failed as expected.

However, when that line is changed to:

```js
expect(elem).toHaveTextContaining('BBBest Sellers');
```

then the test passed again.

Why is that?  I thought whether we `await` or not, that promise should fail regardless.

And in fact it seems a bit fragile, because if a programmer forgot to put await there, the test passes but indeed it may not have passed.  But somebody told me we can have a linting rule to guarantee it... but some hobbyist are going to write scripts and not going to use eslint to guard against that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your function is async, you should await for promises. Removing awaits has sense in sync mode. [Answer about async and await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594596/async-function-without-await-in-javascript)
2. Sync mode is removed from wdio and NodeJS v16 [Sync vs. Async Mode](https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async). So you will have to use async and await in further versions
3. I think you have a typo in `expect(elem).toHaveTextContaining('Best Sellers');`. If you want it to fail it should be `expect(elem).toHaveTextContaining('BBBest Sellers');`

Comment: for (2) didn't know there is such change...  isn't it true if there is a sync mode and we do a `browser.pause(3000)`, it has to do a "busy" idle loop... but in async mode, do we do an `await browser.pause(3000)` so that it is non busy? (just a setTimeout really to wake us up).  For (3), I got it... it is fixed now in the question... you were talking about the "without `await` it passed again" part

Comment: (2) From my understanding you are right. (3) It passes because you don't await for the execution. It returns a promise instead of result